# How do I limit the max number of item rows in a DetailsList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

How do I tell a [`DetailsList`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/detailslist) to only show X rows and a scrollbar for accessing the rest? I'm sure I'm just missing something fairly obvious.

I can do it passing in `styles` for the `root`, but that causes both a vertical and horizontal scrollbar and I'm sure it's not the right way to do it with UI Fabric.

Here's a minimal example showing doing it that way:

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { DetailsList } = Fabric;

const items = [
"alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo",
"foxtrot", "golf", "hotel", "indigo", "juliet",
"lima", "mike", "november", "oscar", "papa",
"romeo", "sierra", "tango", "uniform", "victor",
"whiskey", "x-ray", "yankee", "zulu"
].map(name => ({name, key: name}));

const columns = [
    {
        name: "Name",
        fieldName: "name"
    }
];

const App = () => {
    return (
        <DetailsList
            columns={columns}
            items={items}
            styles={{root: {maxHeight: "15em"}}}
        />
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/office-ui-fabric-react@7/dist/office-ui-fabric-react.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/@uifabric/react-hooks@7/dist/react-hooks.js"></script>
```

I don't want to hack this with CSS,¹ though, I want to do it the UI Fabric way... :-)

---

¹ *(not because CSS is hacky, it isn't; but because I suspect there's a "correct" way to do this with UI Fabric)*

Comment: Trying to make sure I'm following the question / goal. Are you looking for something that says I only want to show 10 rows and the rest overflow? (10 could be any number)

Comment: From the docs, the DetailsList is a derivative of the List component. Looking at [their examples](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/list) they apply a css maxHeight on the list. CSS might be the only way to do that.

Comment: Actually.. looking at the props, it looks like you may be able to use `renderCount`

Comment: @JohnRuddell - Thank you! Sorry for the delay responding, I got unexpectedly called away. I should have mentioned I'd tried `renderCount`; it works in that it only shows X items, but doesn't show any indication there are more (a scrollbar, etc.).

Comment: @JohnRuddell - Nice catch on the fact the list examples are restricted. Looks like they're doing that with a `Stack` though sadly they don't include that code in the code they show you / export to CodePen. So I'm off to investigate limiting it with `Stack`. :-)

Comment: @JohnRuddell - The examples limit it by using CSS (on a container rather than the list itself). So maybe they *do* leave this to CSS... Example: https://codepen.io/tjcrowder/pen/bGdmZVx I'll wait to see if there's another approach, but CSS is fine with me provided I'm not fighting against the framework rather than working with it. :-)

Comment: Yea thats what I was calling out in my second comment, if you view the code in their documentation pages, they supply a max height on the container so the list scrolls. using renderCount would probably be the most "React" way to do it, but no scroll indicator is a bit silly. One thing you could do to make that better would be to do a bit of a fade at the bottom of the container, that would indicate more rows exist below.

Comment: @JohnRuddell - :-) With `renderCount` it never renders the rest of the list. I'd have to manage `startIndex` as well. I'm happy with a scrollbar, it's just UI Fabric does so much with props that I'd otherwise expect done with CSS that I was wondering if I'd missed something. I think maybe not, though. (I'll still wait a bit before posting the CSS solution.) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[John Ruddell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2733506/john-ruddell) pointed out that the examples are limited in vertical size. They do it by putting the entire example in a container with this CSS:

```
.example-170 {
    max-height: 80vh;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

...which is, in turn, in a container of limited size.

And that does work for my sample case as well. So maybe they do leave this to CSS, I can't find any properties to do it in a more "UI Fabric" way.

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { DetailsList } = Fabric;

const items = [
"alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo",
"foxtrot", "golf", "hotel", "indigo", "juliet",
"lima", "mike", "november", "oscar", "papa",
"romeo", "sierra", "tango", "uniform", "victor",
"whiskey", "x-ray", "yankee", "zulu"
].map(name => ({name, key: name}));

const columns = [
    {
        name: "Name",
        fieldName: "name"
    }
];

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <DetailsList
                columns={columns}
                items={items}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.container {
    max-height: 50vh;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/office-ui-fabric-react@7/dist/office-ui-fabric-react.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/@uifabric/react-hooks@7/dist/react-hooks.js"></script>
```